# Execute a %LIKE% query in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qsqlquery

I want to execute a parameterized in qt using value binding.

This is the code:

```
QString name = "Foo";
query->prepare("SELECT Name, Surname FROM employee WHERE Surname LIKE %:surname%");
query->bindValue(":surname", name);
```

The problem is with the *%* character: it generates an error while executing the query, however i don't known how to use it with qt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not have to use "%" in the prepare but concatenate the QString, on the other hand it is not necessary so far I have not needed to use a QSqlQuery pointer so I recommend not using it since it has a copy constructor.

```
QSqlQuery query;
QString name = "Foo";
query.prepare("SELECT Name, Surname FROM employee WHERE Surname LIKE :surname");
query.bindValue(":surname", QString("%%1%").arg(name));
query.exec();
while(query.next())
    qDebug()<< query.value(0) << query.value(1);
```